# Is IPC slowing this down?

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I understand that there is overhead when using the Multiprocessing module, but this seems to be a high amount and the level of IPC should be fairly low from what I can gather.

Say I generate a large-ish list of random numbers between 1-1000 and want to obtain a list of only the prime numbers. This code is only meant to test multiprocessing on CPU-intensive tasks. Ignore the overall inefficiency of the primality test.

The bulk of the code may look something like this:

```
from random import SystemRandom
from math import sqrt
from timeit import default_timer as time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Manager, cpu_count

rdev = SystemRandom()
NUM_CNT = 0x5000
nums = [rdev.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(NUM_CNT)]
primes = []


def chunk(l, n):
    i = int(len(l)/float(n))
    for j in range(0, n-1):
        yield l[j*i:j*i+i]
    yield l[n*i-i:]


def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 2: return True
    if not n % 2: return False
    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

It seems to me that I should be able to split this up among multiple processes. I have 8 logical cores, so I should be able to use `cpu_count()` as the # of processes.

Serial:

```
def serial():
    global primes
    primes = []
    for num in nums:
        if is_prime(num):
            primes.append(num)  # primes now contain all the values
```

The following sizes of NUM_CNT correspond to the speed:

- 0x500 = 0.00100 sec.
- 0x5000 = 0.01723 sec.
- 0x50000 = 0.27573 sec.
- 0x500000 = 4.31746 sec.

This was the way I chose to do the multiprocessing. It uses the `chunk()` function to split up `nums` into `cpu_count()` (roughly equal) parts. It passes each chunk into a new process, which iterates through them, and then assigns it to an entry of a shared dict variable. The IPC should really occur when I assign the value to the shared variable. Why would it occur otherwise?

```
def loop(ret, id, numbers):
    l_primes = []
    for num in numbers:
        if is_prime(num):
            l_primes.append(num)
    ret[id] = l_primes


def parallel():
    man = Manager()
    ret = man.dict()
    num_procs = cpu_count()
    procs = []
    for i, l in enumerate(chunk(nums, num_procs)):
        p = Process(target=loop, args=(ret, i, l))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    [proc.join() for proc in procs]
    return sum(ret.values(), [])
```

Again, I expect some overhead, but the time seems to be increasing exponentially faster than the serial version.

- 0x500 = 0.37199 sec.
- 0x5000 = 0.91906 sec.
- 0x50000 = 8.38845 sec.
- 0x500000 = 119.37617 sec.

What is causing it to do this? Is it IPC? The initial setup makes me expect some overhead, but this is just an insane amount.

**Edit:**

Here's how I'm timing the execution of the functions:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(hex(NUM_CNT))
    for func in (serial, parallel):
        t1 = time()
        vals = func()
        t2 = time()
        if vals is None:  # serial has no return value
            print(len(primes))
        else:  # but parallel does
            print(len(vals))
        print("Took {:.05f} sec.".format(t2 - t1))
```

The same list of numbers is used each time.

Example output:

```
0x5000
3442
Took 0.01828 sec.
3442
Took 0.93016 sec.
```

Comment: Why do you return data from parallel version but not the serial one?

Comment: It's worth noting that prime testing small numbers is not terribly CPU intensive, so your parallel code has a lot of overhead to overcome and not a whole ton of work to do to in parallel. Try increasing the size of your random numbers by several orders of magnitude and you'll see the parallel code do much better relative to the serial code. I'm also wondering why you don't use `multiprocessing.Pool`, rather than writing your own chunking and IPC system.

Comment: @PureW no particular reason. I wrote the serial version first and since I can't use global variables in the same fashion in the parallel version, I made it return. It was just out of convenience.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks. That did seem to do it. I changed it to the range(0, `10**6`) and added a print statement within the function, and this is the result. http://i.imgur.com/Vneqpyw.gif It's almost as if it's not going in parallel at all.... Also, when I changed it to the range `10**10` and dropped one of the 0's, it did run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. How do you measure time? On my computer, the parallel version is much faster than the serial one.

I'm mesuring using `time.time()` that way: if we assume `tt` is an alias for `time.time()`.

```
serial()
t2 = int(round(tt() * 1000))
print(t2 - t1)
parallel()
t3 = int(round(tt() * 1000))
print(t3-t2)
```

I get, with `0x500000` as input:

- 5519ms for the serial version
- 3351ms for the parallel version

I believe that **your mistake is caused by the inclusion of the number generation process inside the parallel, but not inside the serial one**.

On my computer, the generation of the random numbers takes like 45seconds (it's a very slow process). So, it can explain the difference between your two values as I don't think that my computer uses a very different architecture.

Comment: No.  I thought that was it, too, but I checked. The time does not start until after the numbers are generated. I will update the OP with the exact script I'm using.

Comment: Hmm; very strange. On my computer, with your new code, the parallel version is still much faster than the serial one. Maybe, could you try to increase the size of each number in order to reduce side effects? 

Is it a particular computer or a particular operating system?